# How to plot neat ImageGrid plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I try to plot figures with limited amounts of dead-space on the top, sides, and bottom I use either tight_layout or constrained_layout. However, it seems like ImageGrid doesn't support this. Take a look at the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid

# Data to populate plots.
im = np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 6), constrained_layout=True)
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,
                 nrows_ncols=(5, 2),
                 axes_pad=0.2,
                 label_mode="L")

for ax in grid:
    ax.imshow(im)

fig.suptitle("Testing a suptitle on with ImageGrid")
fig.savefig("imagegrid_suptitle.png")
```

I get the following warning:

> UserWarning: There are no gridspecs with layoutgrids. Possibly did not call parent GridSpec with the "figure" keyword
> fig.savefig("imagegrid_suptitle.png")

And this is the resulting plot: [ImageGrid with constrained_layout=True](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD9d5.png)

As can be seen, there's a lot of dead-space at the top, sides, and bottom, and the suptitle is located far above the top two grids. Is this a bug in constrained_layout, or is it simply not possible to support its use with ImageGrid?

Please note that I have tried to use tight_layout, but that produces a warning about the lack of support for ImageGrid:

> UserWarning: This figure includes Axes that are not compatible with tight_layout, so results might be incorrect.
> fig.tight_layout()

It also results in the suptitle overlapping with the two top grids.

Comment: Yes, `ImageGrid` is not compatible with either layout engine.  Matplotlib hopes to introduce `ImageGrid`-like capability to the main library in the next few releases, but its not done yet.  In the meantime, you can get reasonable results by manually changing the aspect ratio of the figure size to match the aspect ratio of your axes layout.

Comment: @JodyKlymak Thanks for pointing that out! I've found the relevant project in the matplotlib GitHub repo: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/projects/9